# Group by in Django with field distinction

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have two tables, one for products and one for suppliers, I did a query that returns this:

```
select 
    f.nome, f.cnpj, sum(p.quantidade) as "Quantidade de Produtos", 
    count(distinct categoria_id) as "Categorias com Produtos "
from 
    core_produtos p
inner join 
    core_fornecedor f
on 
    p.fornecedor_id=f.id
group by 
    f.nome, f.cnpj
order by 
    f.nome ASC;
```

and she returns a table like this:

```
     nome     |        cnpj        | Quantidade de Produtos | Categorias com Produtos  
--------------+--------------------+------------------------+--------------------------
 fornecedor 1 | 10.331.608/0001-52 |                   7339 |                        5
 fornecedor 2 | 00.333.725/0001-00 |                   7673 |                        5
 fornecedor 3 | 88.550.421/0001-37 |                   8423 |                        5
 fornecedor 4 | 03.251.500/0001-94 |                  14101 |                        5
 fornecedor 5 | 25.862.630/0001-04 |                   8988 |                        5
```

my models in the tables involved:

```
class Produtos(models.Model):

    categoria = models.ForeignKey(
        Categoria, related_name="produtos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(
        Fornecedor, related_name="fornecedores", on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=225)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.TextField(blank=True)
    preco = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantidade = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    disponivel = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Produto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Produtos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

```
class Fornecedor(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Fornecedo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Fornecedores"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cnpj
```

**my question is:**
how do I query using django's ORM?

Comment: Giving you Django's models definition could help.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand

Comment: To use Django's ORM, you have to declare [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/). Did you do so ? If yes, could you provide the models' definitions ?

Comment: ready, I posted it down here

Comment: ok, sorry, i'm new around here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) :

```py
from django.db.models import Sum, Count

Fornecedor.objects.annotate(
    quantidade_de_produtos=Sum("fornecedores__quantidade"),
    categorias_com_produtos=Count("categoria__id", distinct=True),
).order_by("nome")
```

This will return a `QuerySet` in which each instance will have the attributes `quantidade_de_produtos` and `categorias_com_produtos` containing the results of the annotation.

---

The annotation are done on the `quantidade` field the `Fornecedor` table using [lookup that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). This is done using two underscores `__`to travel through relations (in this case `fornecedores` and `quantidade`, which are both `ForeignKey`).

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, but you could talk to me about it as well, I tried to use the annotate several times but I couldn't.
I don't understand how he had access to the table with the quantidade column if it's in the produtos table

Comment: @pedrolukas Edited my answer with more informations